# How to add a given number of days to a django DateTimeField

Tags: django

I have a model with a field containing a DateTimeField and a function to calculate a return date based on this DateTimeField. How would I add a given number of days to this????

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    startdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    enddate = models.DateField()

    def save(self)
        self.enddate = self.startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This however does not work

Comment: enddate is of DateField type, where as the value that you are trying to store is of DateTime type.  You can try by changing the enddate type to DateTime type.

Comment: When I try that I get unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: Since startDate has 'auto_now_add=True', you are getting that error. startdate will gets the value only after object creation. Hence when you try to add timedelta you are getting that error

Comment: You can have default value for startdate as (default_value=timezone.now()). This is a workaround, not sure it suits your requirement.